# Android error when trying to run app: :app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug

Tags: android

I am unable to run app in my android studio and it is giving me this stack trace which is mentioned further below. I am unsure how to fix it and I tried setting `multiDexEnabled true` in the build gradle settings but still having the issue:

build grade settings:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tecocraft.challenge_reward"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    realm {
        syncEnabled = true;
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'

    implementation "org.parceler:parceler-api:1.0.3"

    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.3'

    //implementation 'io.realm:realm-android:0.82.1'
   // implementation 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'

    implementation 'com.github.ViksaaSkool:AwesomeSplash:v1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.github.dimorinny:floating-text-button:0.0.4'

    implementation 'com.github.markushi:circlebutton:1.1'

    implementation 'com.github.medyo:fancybuttons:1.8.4'

    implementation 'com.ufreedom.uikit:FloatingViewLib:1.0.2'
}
```

stack trace:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\31.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\32.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\33.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\34.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\36.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\37.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\38.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\39.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\40.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\41.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\42.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\43.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\44.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\45.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\46.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\47.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\48.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\49.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\50.jar
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\31.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\32.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\33.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\34.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\36.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\37.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\38.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\39.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\40.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\41.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\42.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\43.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\44.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\45.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\46.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\47.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\48.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\49.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\50.jar
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransform.transform(DexMergerTransform.java:225)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3.jar, C:\Users\mmkp1\Documents\Challenge_Reward\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar...
```

Answer (score 1):

You must include this dependency

```
dependencies {
 implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Reason:

Your minSdkVersion is 15 and multidex is not natively  supported below API Version 21.Hope it helps!

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)